# How can the menu Options on Synology-NAS DSM be opened via JS, JQ or EXTJS script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, synology

I'm trying to automate some entries in a Synology NAS with JavaScript.
The web-based operating system DSM seems to have been created with Ext JS 3.X.
In contrast to the “Main Menu”, the “Options” menu cannot be opened by sending a JS or JQ “click” event. The "Options" menu only responds to manual clicks.

Options menu

[image]

Main menu

[image]

Firefox Inspector

[image]

````
```
// JS
document.getElementById("ext-gen184").click() // Element-ID Main Menu, works.
document.getElementById("ext-gen33").click()  // Element-ID Options Menu, works not!
```
```
// JQ
$("ext-gen184").click() // Element-ID Main Menu, works
$("ext-gen33").click()  // Element-ID Options Menu, works not!
```
```
// ExtJS
var elm = Ext.ComponentMgr.get("ext-gen33")
```
returns undefined
````

The blur and focus events of both elements are stored with this function:

````
```
function I(M) {
  if (!Ext) {
    return
  }
  M = Ext.EventObject.setEvent(M);
  var L;
  if (D.delegate) {
    if (!(L = M.getTarget(D.delegate, E))) {
      return
    }
  } else {
    L = M.target
  } if (D.stopEvent) {
    M.stopEvent()
  }
  if (D.preventDefault) {
    M.preventDefault()
  }
  if (D.stopPropagation) {
    M.stopPropagation()
  }
  if (D.normalized === false) {
    M = M.browserEvent
  }
  J.call(K || E, M, L, D)
}
```
````

I'm new to JS. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems to be easier to turn water into wine...

Answer (score 2):

DSM is based on an extension of ExtJS 3.4 framework.

This extension is not documented as far as I know but you can find some partial information on writing an ExtJS application for DSM here :

https://github.com/DigitalBox98/SimpleExtJSApp